# All variables are null at the request with Axios to ASP.Net Core Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, axios

Here is my client request code:

```
import request from 'axios';

//...

     let url = 'Login/SignIn',
                headers = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                },
                data = JSON.stringify( {
                    name: 'danil',
                    password: 'pwd'
                });

     request.post(url, data, headers);
```

looks fine by the first glance.

Request is pending here:
[image]

But it all ended up like that in  my controller:

[image]

Here's the code btw:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn([FromBody]string name, [FromBody]string password)
        {

            var userLoginCommand = new UserLogInCommand {
                Login = name,
                Password = password
            };

            await _dispatcher.DispatchAsync(userLoginCommand);
            return Content(userLoginCommand.Result, "application/json");
        }
```

Whats wrong with it? What did I forgot?

I tried to play around with `JSON.stringify` by adding it and removing, tried to not sending headers (and then it throws `415 error`) but no changes there. Still got nulls.

**UPD**:
As Ali suggested in comments, passing data is goes fine if we use `LoginModel` for this like that:

```
 public class LoginModel
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
        }
```

[image]

But why it's not going work just like that in a simple way?

Comment: Have you tried to create class with `name` and `password` properties and pass it like the following `Task<ActionResult> SignIn([FromBody]LoginModel model)`?

Comment: Nope, it should work like that as well isn't it? DTO is an option yep, but still

Comment: @Ali created and it works like that, with model but

Comment: Please read first note in section **Binding formatted data from the request body** [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: @Ali oh, I see. afaik it was working in asp.net mvc, looks like now things quite changed

Comment: why isnt working in the simple way??

Answer (score 1):

Only one parameter is allowed to read from the message body.
In your example you have two parameters with FromBody attribute, that's why you have null values.

Please find documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

*"At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body."*